# Rotate right triangle with perimeter 1 about the hypotenuse

Tags: triangles, volume

We rotate every right triangle with perimeter 1 about its hypotenuses. Is it true that we can choose a solid from so obtained solids that has maximum volume? If yes, what's the volume? I guess I should use derivative in the end, but what to do at first?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Maximum volume among what possible shapes?  Are you talking about a fixed right triangle, but considering rotating it about each of its three sides?

Comment: Question is not clear. Are there more than one right angled triangle?

Comment: We rotate every right triangles with perimeter 1.

Comment: Is it now clear?

Comment: No.  When you ask about a maximum, you have to be clear about what set it is the maximum among.  Are you considering all shapes of perimeter $1$ being rotated about all possible axes?  Do the shapes have to be polygons?  Do they have to be convex?  Does one of the axis of rotation have to coincide with one of the sides of the shape?

Comment: I mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution

Comment: And I wrote that we rotete only about hypotenuses.

Comment: Is your question about *which* triangle of perimeter $1$ yields the largest volume when rotated about its hypotenuse (assuming a maximum exists)?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know whether maximum exists.

Answer (score 1):

In a right triangle with legs $x$ and $y$ and hypotenuse $z$, the altitude, perpendicular to the hypotenuse has length
$$
r = \frac{xy}{z} = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.
$$
When you rotate the right triangle about the hypotenuse, the solid shape consists of two cones of radius $r$ and combined height $z$.  So the total volume (using Archimedes' formula) is
$$
V = \frac{\pi}{3}zr^2 = \frac{\pi}{3}z \Bigl( \frac{xy}{z} \Bigr)^2
= \frac{\pi x^2 y^2}{3z} = \frac{\pi x^2 y^2}{3\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}.
$$
Now the perimeter constraint $P = 1$ amounts to
$$
x + y + z = 1
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x + y + \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 1.
$$

This is a standard constrained optimization problem, which can be solved using the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).  The objective function that you're trying to maximize is $V = V(x,y)$ and the constraint is
$P(x, y) = 1$.  Solving the system of equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\dfrac{dV}{dx} &= \lambda \dfrac{dP}{dx}, \\
\dfrac{dV}{dy} &= \lambda \dfrac{dP}{dy}, \\
P &= 1
\end{align}
\right.
$$
yields
$$
x = y = \frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}},
$$
which corresponds to the case of the *isosceles* right triangle (half of a square).

Comment: How to do that without Lagrange multipliers, using only derivatives?